# Angular custom form element directive before ngSubmit validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

so suppose I have a form:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <custom-form-element><custom-form-element>
    <button name="submit">Submit<button>
<form>
```

Is there anyway to do something with the data the `customFormElement` is containing (assume it's some sort of custom field) in the `link` (or somewhere else, if appropriate?) part of the directive definition to validate / sanitize the data there before the form submission?

I don't want to do this in the `submitForm()` function because there could be multiple of this same element there.

EDIT: might be helpful to say that what I'm doing isn't validation per se, but more like...`customFormElement` modifies a specific property on scope. e.g.

```
$scope.customFormElementData = {};
```

Then right before submission it'll look like:

```
$scope.customFormElementData = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'quuz'
};
```

But what I want to do is in the case that:

```
$scope.customFormElementData = {
    foo: '',
    baz: ''
}
```

I want to omit both foo and bar.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials and docs on how to use form control validators using ngModel controller

Comment: can you link one example? I'm probably just googling the wrong things, but I'm mostly just getting back results about entire form validation.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into whether or not what you are trying to accomplish is the best approach, you can do what you have in mind by broadcasting events.

So in your `SubmitForm()` function:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('aboutToSubmitForm');
$rootScope.$broadcast('submittingForm');
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.$on('submittingForm', function() { //form submittal logic here });
```

Then, in your directive's linking function:

```
$scope.$on('aboutToSubmitForm', function(){ //your pre form submission logic here });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're implying that this isn't the best approach though right? Care to get a bit into what the best one is?

Comment: I only said that because you got a comment about using the standard validation technique, but after giving it more some more thought, I really don't think that applies here.  I think my response is the best way to handle this.